# What is this startup error with Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bundle

I wanted to use Android `Eclipse` in my computer. But there is a problem which is blocking the `eclipse.exe` from running.

The Java `JDK` which is required for `Eclipse` to work, is already available. I have even updated Java to the latest version (1.8). But the problem persists.

Please check the image for the error

[image]

As shown in the image, I can't find this path in the specified folder,

> ...\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe

I also referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466661/javaw-exe-and-eclipse-startup-problems) but, I have set up %PATH% environment variable to Maven, which, I am using in other projects

What is the issue and how to rectify it ?

Comment: did you install a new Java version recently?

Comment: This may be relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974332/eclipse-mars-wont-start-after-java-8-update-71/34974375#34974375

Comment: Yes I have updated Java, but still the problem persists

Comment: make sure all three are of same type if you have 32bit sdk then you need 32 bit jvm/jre and 32bit eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to google and download the latest java `JDK`.
Its `JDK 1.8`.

Here is the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
Select your os and accept the agreement to start download.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have updated Java to the latest version. I have also edited my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the path of Javaw.exe in project properties

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/sdk/index.html).

> Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse has ended, per our [announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html). You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see [Migrating from Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).